# Query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: sql, ms-access, forms

I'm really hoping that somebody could help me regarding this problem. I am using Microsoft Access 2007 to build some forms while connecting to my sql database. Everything seems ok except the forms inserting data in the database showing this kind of message

"Query input must contain at least one table or query"

I'm not finding where the exact problem is!! Can anyone give me any helpful advice what to do? I would really appreciate any kind of advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the SQL and / or the code from a sample form.

Comment: What is the source of your form ?
If it is a linked table, try open that table.

Comment: Sounds like you're not really using Access, since inserting records shouldn't require executing SQL in code.

Answer (score 2):

What is the sql (you might find it in the logfile of the server)?

There might be a problem in the FROM part.